# Can you explain why do we have to access bytes variable "functionCallData" four times in order to get selector?

Tags: solidity, function-selector

Why would we get function selector like this and why do we use that bytes variable functionCallData do many times? Thanks in advance!

```
function getSelectorTwo() public view returns (bytes4 selector) {
        bytes memory functionCallData = abi.encodeWithSignature(
            "transfer(address,uint256)",
            address(this),
            123
        );
        selector = bytes4(
            bytes.concat(
                functionCallData[0],
                functionCallData[1],
                functionCallData[2],
                functionCallData[3]
            )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bytes` type is like an array, where each element in the array is 1 byte.

The `getSelectorTwo()` function is encoding the `transfer(address,uint256)` function selector with the values of the parameters it expects (`address` and  `uint256`).

If you printed `functionCallData` you would see the following bytes:

`0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000059235ef80c8c63b480734c6888754f464fdb212d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b`

Notice how the first four bytes are the function selector `a9059cbb`.

Then the following 32 bytes are the address of that contract (left-padded with zeros):

`00000000000000000000000059235ef80c8c63b480734c6888754f464fdb212d`

Then the following 32 bytes are the `123` number in hex (left-padded with zeros):

`000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b`

`7b` hex is `123` in decimal.

So, the reason why that code is accessing the `functionCallData` bytes array 4 times is because it is copying the first 4 bytes of that data, which we know it's the function selector:

`functionCallData[0] = a9 functionCallData[1] = 05 functionCallData[2] = 9c functionCallData[3] = bb`
It concatenates it and returns it.

It cannot do something like `functionCallData[0:4]` to copy a range from the `functionCallData` bytes array because the slice operator is only available in `calldata` bytes array, not on local or storage arrays (yet). So it has to copy it manually, whether in a loop or index by index like it's doing.

Check and try my `getTransferFunctionSelectorWithParams` function below:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Contract {

   function getTransferFunctionSelectorWithParams() public view returns(bytes memory) {
       bytes memory functionCallData = abi.encodeWithSignature(
            "transfer(address,uint256)",
            address(this),
            123
        );
        return functionCallData;
   }

   function getSelectorTwo() public view returns (bytes4 selector) {
        bytes memory functionCallData = abi.encodeWithSignature(
            "transfer(address,uint256)",
            address(this),
            123
        );
        selector = bytes4(
            bytes.concat(
                functionCallData[0],
                functionCallData[1],
                functionCallData[2],
                functionCallData[3]
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a function calldata is prefixed with a 4 byte selector. The encoding standard is to add 4 bytes first before the input before encoding. That is why you have to access bytes variable 4 times in order to get to the selector.